# Ширина и высота imageView всегда 0, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: android, xml

```
private fun getSpin() {

    val angle = Random.nextInt(3600 - 360) + 360

    val pivotX: Float = image_rotate.width / 2f // всегда 0
    val pivotY: Float = image_rotate.height / 2f // всегда 0

    Log.d("ImageHeight", image_rotate.height.toString())
    Log.d("ImageWidth", image_rotate.width.toString())
    img_btn_flop.setOnClickListener {
        val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
            (if (lastAngle == -1) 0 else lastAngle).toFloat(),
            angle.toFloat(),
            pivotX,
            pivotY
        )

        lastAngle = angle

        rotateAnimation.duration = 1100
        rotateAnimation.fillAfter = true
        image_rotate.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)

        img_btn_flop.isEnabled = false

    }
}
```

Я пишу анимацию вращения и дял этого у меня есть 2 строчки, которые делят ширину и высоту на 2, но при этом ширина и высота всегда приходит 0. С чем это может быть связано? Может ли это быть связано с тем, что я не вызываю findViewById в методе onCreateView, а напрямую обращаюсь к xml разметке?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_btn_flop"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/flop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_rotate"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wheel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_stop"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Я уже пробовал инициализировать ширину и высоту в onCreateView, но это не помогло и все равно ширина и высота равна 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша `view` еще не отрисована, её высота и ширина не просчитана. Что можно сделать:

1. использовать `view.post { }`
2. добавить слушателя `view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` (не забыть удалить слушателя)
3. пробовать `View.getMeasuredWidth()` и `View.getMeasuredHeigth()`

Прошу добавить другие способы.